# Running OpenDaylight on VirtualBox - error

Tags: java, virtualbox, sdn, opendaylight

I'm running OpenDayLight (distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium) on VirtualBox (Ubuntu). I think I have installed all necessary programs, but I get this error:

```
./bin/karaf: 242: [: Illegal number:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UnsyncloadClass; support was removed in 11.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/endorsed: 
/home/pati/distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/lib/endorsed is not supported. 
Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Since yesterday I have been reading about solutions but none of them worked.
Has anyone got this error before, or know any solutions?

I also tried running it on my computer without VM it works, but I need it on Virtualbox.

Comment: 0.4.0-Beryllium? That unsupported version for a quite long time.

Comment: You should pick something recent from https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/

Comment: @rkosegi, but new releases don't have dlux and I'm just starting so I think it will be easier

Comment: if you just starting, then it make even more sense to use something supported. You will come across more problems without support from community when using something unsupported

Comment: @rkosegi Ok, thanks :) I will try

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I had to change java version from 11 to 8 and it helped.